# Mobile app native or not recommendations

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, mobile-application

I am looking to get some crowd insights with which framework to based our development efforts while creating our mobile app

Mainly the application should present aggregated content in an appealing way and nice animations between transitions and button clicks, it should support payment integration options, and deep linking mechanism.

We are at the point were we debate the options to go the progressive web path or going the traditional native (iOS and Android) development process

What would you recommend

Thank you all
Oren

Comment: If you ask my personal opinion I would always stick to the native solution. Will be less pain

Comment: Look if you are looking for fast development & low cost then go for Hybrid. Some hybrid platforms are too well such as Ionic.If you have huge database & too much custom animation then go for native. Absolutely Native is native.

Comment: The deeper the integration with the OS, the more you need to develop native apps. The more closely you want to match each platforms HIG, the more you need to develop native apps. This is basically an opinion-based question but from what you have said I would recommend native apps - provided you can deal with twice the development costs.

Answer (score 0):

Now at this point of time if you are looking for a rich application and you want flawless design architecture with animations and then  you must go for native integration. It will cost you more but it worths. In native development all the APIs will be available easily with proper documentation of each platform. You need not to worry about error handling much.

---

If you choose to go for hybrid app then you must go for react native as phonegap will be a bad option. As phonegap use an webview in which UI handling will be a hard task to achive. But it will cost you less.

Comment: React Native apps are Native apps and not Hybrid apps like Cordova/Phone Gap apps, as the UI layer is trans-compiled to native UI and JS code is run by JS VM, without any need to have a webview like hybrid solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346715/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-pwa-only-greenfield-project) is a detailed view on PWA and here is on [comparison with other options](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/choose-between-progressive-web-apps-react-native-nativescript-2018).

From what you have explained on what is needed, PWA should be a cost effective and still good performing option, followed by Native Script/React Native and lastly Native(due to cost of development for multi platforms).